Generalizied Fourier Transform and Inversion Formula
For $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that its Fourier transform $\widehat{f}$ is still in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ we have the well-known Fourier inversion formula
$f(x)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^d}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \widehat{f}(\xi)e^{ix\cdot \xi} d\xi $.
Note that the complex exponentials $e_\xi(x):=e^{ix\cdot \xi}$ are "formally" eigenfunctions of the self-adjoint operator $D:=\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dx}$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ by which I mean that although $e_\xi$ is obivously not a $L^2$-function, however, we still have "$De_\xi=\xi e_\xi$" in a pointwise sense. Thus the Fourier inversion formula reads
$f=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \widehat{f}(\xi) e_\xi d \xi$.
I am stuck at some problem for which it would be nice if I had an analogous "Fourier expansion" at hand in a more general setting: Suppose that $D$ is now a self-adjoint  operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R}; \mathbb{C}^2; d\mu)$ (so $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}^2$ is vector-valued and $\mu=\rho dx$ for some bi-Lipschitz density $\rho$) and $(e_\xi)_{\xi\in \mathbb{R}}$ is a family of sufficiently regular bounded functions such that $D e_\xi=\xi e_\xi$ in a pointwise sense. Define $\widehat{f}(\xi):=(f,e_{\xi}):=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\overline{e_\xi}(x)d x$ (a priori for $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ ). Under which hypothesis on $D$ can one hope for some "Fourier expansion"
$f=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \widehat{f}(\xi) e_\xi d\xi$
at least for "nice" $f$? In my case $D$ is a pertubation of the usual derivative and I was not able to reproduce some sort of Fourier inversion formula. Any hints are greatly appreciated.

You are just describing the spectral theorem, which is different from the Fourier transform.

@LPZ thanks for the reply. Which version of the spectral theorem are you referring to? It is not clear to me that the unitary transformation from the spectral theorem has to do anything with the $(e_\xi)\xi$. In fact, it is not clear at all that the "abstract Fourier transform" as defined above is even unitary. The $(e\xi)_\xi$ have to be orthornormal in some sense, but it appears to me, that Fourier-Inversion as above somehow makes use of the specific easy structure of complex exponentials.
